# Update/Clean offline Visual Studio installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I download the Visual Studio installer locally and let other team members use it. Whenever there is a new update, I run the command "[path to exe] --layout [path to offline installer] --lang en-US". This will download only the new packages, but doesn't delete the outdated packages from the offline installer folder. Is there way to do that? Because my offline installer folder has been growing. It is around 40GB now.